# Multiple Counts from the same row with range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get number of transactions within the week given start date and end date.The below query works fine for one day 2011-10-14

```
SELECT COUNT(operationId) AS trans
  FROM hwfg_t_Tracking 
  WHERE hitTime BETWEEN '2011-10-14 00:00:00' AND '2011-10-14 23:59:59.99'
GO
```

How can I get the count on operationId where hitTime between 14,13,12,11,10,9,8(1 week) with the single SELECT statement. Like number of transactions for 2011-10-14 as a column, 2011-10-13 as another column and so on

Comment: Don't use `BETWEEN` for `datetime`. Best to use `>=  ..... <`. You need a `PIVOT` or cross tab query.

Comment: the above query is working fine, but I need to retrieve more columns from the operationsId with the hitTime range changing from say 14 to 8

Comment: If hitTime is of type `datetime` you will be missing anything with hitTime = '2011-10-14 23:59:59.993' or '2011-10-14 23:59:59.997' If hitTime is `datatime2` and has precision explicitly defined of 0, 1 or 2, then the where clause is correct. Too much double checking types involved, see Martin Smith's comment for how to avoid all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query for **one row per day** in your specified range:

```
SELECT cast(hitTime AS date) AS mydate, COUNT(operationId) AS trans
FROM   hwfg_t_Tracking
WHERE  hitTime >= '2011-10-14 00:00:00' AND hitTime < '2011-10-21 00:00:00'
GROUP  BY cast(hitTime AS date)
```

Or, if you want them **all in one row**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_sum
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN cast(dt As date) = '2011-10-14' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS day14
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN cast(dt As date) = '2011-10-15' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS day15
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN cast(dt As date) = '2011-10-16' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS day16
-- etc.
FROM   hwfg_t_Tracking
WHERE  hitTime >= '2011-10-14 00:00:00' AND hitTime < '2011-10-21 00:00:00'
```

Comment: What if I pass the startDate(2011-10-08) and endDate(2011-10-14) as arguements will I be able to get count of operationId for each single day as a row ?

Comment: @Naveen: The first query works for **any** time range. The second one you'll have to adapt to your time range, should be obvious. The other option is pivot tables, but they are more complicated, IMO. [Read more in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).